# Research community around logistics micro-economic topics?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, technology

Is there the equivalent of a Rand Journal of Economics for the topic of logistics, focusing on the micro-economics of productivity gains via automation or disruptive technologies.

There is the wonderful macroeconomic work by Carlota Perez on effect of technology disruption on financial capital, which helps me think about logistics etc., but in scouring Google, I find a paucity of micro-economic research on the area of logistics and supply chain and manufacturing processes. I am sure I am missing the elephant in the room, any tips for where it is ?